# looping s3.putObject process only the first 3 requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So, I am trying to fetch and download stream data from an URL in my database.  From there I am trying to put that downloaded content in an s3 bucket, however, out of the 5 URLs, only the first three get process.   Here is my code for my loop

```
const uploadToS3 = async (uploadData) =>{

    for (const file of uploadData){
            const {data, headers} = await axios.get(file.attachment_url, {responseType: 'stream'});
        try {
            console.log(file.attachment_url)
                const objectParams = {
                    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
                    Key: 'Resume'+'_'+file.candidate_id+' _ '+file.candidate_first_name,
                    ContentLength: headers['content-length'],
                    Body: data
                };
            await  s3.putObject(objectParams).promise();
        }catch (e){
                console.log(e)
        }

    }
console.log('Finished')

}
```

Has anyone run into this? it also throws this error which I cant figure out either.

```
errorRequestTimeout: Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.
```

I have checked and all three URLs do get passed to this function.   It just only processes 3 of 5.

Comment: Try using upload instead of putObject.

Comment: Your title implies this is about s3 but are you sure it isn't the GET request which is failing?

Comment: @404 no, Ive double check that I was getting data from each URL and indeed I am.

Comment: @404 it turned out to be a duplicate key issue with S3.  it was overwriting the duplicate name keys.

Comment: @Mu-Majid  it turned out to be a duplicate key issue with S3.  it was overwriting the duplicate name keys.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the size of the files you're trying to upload, but `putObject` is mostly used for a small file uploads and if the size is large you might get a timeout error.

Try using `upload()` instead as it has a lot of feature handled for you under the hood, like multi part uploads.

Answer (score 0):

so it actually turned out to be an issue with the objectParams key.  Since they are URLs for the same `ID` aws s3 was skipping over those with the same key.  For example

```
 Key: 'Resume'+'_'+file.candidate_id+'_'+file.attachment_filename,
```

those that had the same key name (which was the one I was missing).  AWS was skipping over them or not overwriting the ones that were already uploaded.